# Form string from input parameter values inside informix sp

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, informix

What i want to do , and i dont have any idea of some function to do it, is,
how to form a string from all input parameters that are used to call the procedure itself.
Lets say

```
execute procedure test(1,2,3)
```

Inside this procedure i want to have some smart code that will form string like this **1,2,3** 
I know that the simplest way is to concatanate the input string values, but i have a lot of procedures and with a different number of input parameters.

I want to keep log , lets say if my sp crash, i want to insert log in a table with the values the sp was called with :)

Anyone have idea?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  It sounds like you're trying to do something that perhaps you shouldn't?  *(Because there may be a better RDBMS suited approach.)*

Comment: Not a clear question, could you be more specific

Comment: I want to keep log , lets say if my sp crash, i want to insert log in a table with the values the sp was called with :)

Comment: Are you somehow looking to format all the parameters of any input type into a string?  Or just specific types.  Your example has three integers (numbers); that's pretty easy.  But if you need to handle 1-6 parameters, and those could be numbers, dates, strings, etc, then it is harder.  Are you expecting to have to write the call to your stringizing function with the correct argument list, or are you hoping to have it done automatically, somehow?  Handling any given set of values is not a huge problem; trying to handle any possible set of values is more of a problem.

Comment: How big do you expect the argument lists to be?  How many arguments?  What are the longest string types that need to be handled?  Does the code need to be able to encode strings so that embedded commas or quotes etc do not confuse the parser?

Comment: The max number of input parameters is from 25-30. There are diferent types like varchar, char(255), date, datetime, integer that are used in each procedure. Once again to be clear , i want to form a string from all values from the input parameters in row, and if my sp crashes on exeption to record that string in a table, in order , later to be much easier to debug my procedures :)